# How to make sure filesystem is mounted rw and not corrupt

Tags: scripting, filesystems, boot, remote, e2fsck

During the last year I have deployed around 20 embedded systems to various locations. The last month I have encountered that I was not able to SSH into two of them. Upon going to the actual devices and investigating, it turned out that the partition with the filesystem was corrupted, and after running e2fsck and rebooting, they worked again.

After this I updated the systems with a systemd service that runs this script upon boot:

```
partitions="/dev/mmcblk1p2"
for partition in $partitions; do
if mount | grep $partition | grep ro;
    then /sbin/fsck $partition -y && reboot;
fi
done
```

So far I haven't had any more corrupted partitions, but I am still worried that this is not enough. Is this really adequate, or are there any other measures I should take to ensure that I will not encounter this problem again?

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Isn't it in the case of errors being detected (and possibly repaired) that I would want to reboot the system, so that it will hopefully be mounted rw on the next boot? I was thinking that by not being dependent on that, I could end up in a reboot loop in the case where the partition is mounted as read only every boot, and e2fsck is not able to detect or fix any errors.

Comment: I dont know what sorts of embedded system your using but if stored on flash drives, you have to know that flash is not really reliable and could get corrupted quiet easilly compared to other storage such as hdd or ssd

Comment: @Kiwy I use the embedded MMC (or eMMC if you prefer). I am working on ways of making it less likely to corrupt the partitions on it, and I'm grateful for any help I get.